# Config Symfony2 on Windows XP

Tags: php, windows, symfony, path

I have a little knowledge about PHP, I want to implement Symfony2, I have successfully installed and config Symfony2 using .../Symfony/web/config.php.

For now I'm going to create a bundle using php command, but I really don't know at all about this.

I tried this:

[image]

I got this result:

[image]

I'm using EasyPHP and I believe I have config the path to cover it's directory, most tutorial is about UNIX-like system, please suggest me how to do this on Windows XP.

Thanks All.
Kongthap.

Comment: did u use wamp or xammp web server?

Comment: Could you show us your PATH environment variable? It seems it is misinterpreted (perhaps a single/double quotes problem)

Comment: I'm using EasyPHP, this is the path I just added.
C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.0\php\php5314x120712102600\